# How can I copy an entire column of data (the number of rows are not fixed) to a new column in the same excel file, in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file containing a column of 'Usernames' and I want to copy-paste that data into the adjacent column in the same sheet and call it 'Passwords'. All this must be done in a Python program.

Comment: And what did you try so far?

Comment: Kindly create an example , read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: in the name of all that is good, I hope this is only an experiment -- you aren't *really* going to be setting all your users' passwords to be the same as their username, right?  nor give them all a password *based on* their username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html):

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('testsheet.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
wb  = writer.book
df = pd.read_excel("testsheet.xlsx")
df['Passwords'] = df['Usernames']

df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
wb.save('testsheet.xlsx')
```

Alternatively, you can try a more simpler solution:

```
df = pd.read_excel('testsheet.xlsx')
df['password'] = df['username']
df.to_excel("testsheet.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.copy`. Suppose this is your dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel('username.xlsx')
    df
```

This gives you:

```
 username
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
```

Then create another dataframe:

```
df1 = df.copy()
```

Then after copying the content , create a column with the name of 'password' in `df` and equate it to `df1`

```
df['password'] = df1
df
```

This gives you:

```
  username   password
0    a        a
1    b        b
2    c        c
3    d        d
```

Then save it to excel:

```
df.to_excel('username.xlsx' , index = False)
```